# Dynamic datasource of an android listview

Tags: android, listview, dynamic, datasource

Each time the listview activity is loaded, I query the database and get a collection of collections of name value pairs representing the properties of my model. I wish to then parse one of them and build the list item layout. How can I achieve that? I can't seem to find a way with listview adapters.

So far my plan is to create an object with a few indexed serializable fields and set their values with my KVPs using reflection, and then setting the object as the listview's datasource.

```
private Serializable Property0;
    private Serializable Property1;
    private Serializable Property2;
    private Serializable Property3;
    private Serializable Property4;
    private Serializable Property5;
```

Does anyone have a better idea?